# Asserting that Mockito mocked object gets set to null

Tags: android, junit, mockito

I am using Mockito to do JUnit tests, and stuck figuring out an assertion issue. I'm creating a mock object, and then creating a presenter object using the mocked object.

```
@Mock
Object mFooBar;

private FooPresenter mFooPresenter;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    mFooPresenter = new FooPresenter(mFooBar);

}
```

In the onDestroy() method in my presenter, I null out the object.

```
public FooPresenter(Object fooBar) {
    mFooBar = fooBar;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mFooBar = null;
}
```

Then when I try to assertNull for mFooBar in my FooPresenterTest, it fails because it is not null.

```
@Test
public void testThatObjectsAreNullifiedInOnDestroy() throws Exception {
    fooPresenter.onDestroy();

    assertNull(mFooBar);
}
```

This fails as

```
Expected :<null>
Actual :mFooBar
```

My questions then are, how are the references handled to the mocked objects in my test class compared to the object I instantiated to run the test? Why does assertNull fail when it should have been set to null?

Comment: Hey @kerseyd27, I'm assuming the the `mFooBar` field in your `FooPresenter` is private, is there any property exposing it?

Comment: Hey @abest Yes it is private, and there are no exposing properties for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kerseyd27,

From your test name `testThatObjectsAreNullifiedInOnDestroy` it appears that you're looking to verify that injected `mFooBar` object is released by your presenter when the presenter is destroyed.

First, to directly answer your questions:

> how are the references handled to the mocked objects in my test class compared to the object I instantiated to run the test?

I'll let these answers([link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/3166366), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40499/3166366)) speak for themselves, but explain how it pertains to your issue. The mocked object is instantiated in the Test class and passed by value into the `FooPresenter`.  The `FooPresenter.mFooBar` is a *separate* reference(belonging to the presenter) that points to the mocked object.  Until the `onDestroy` method is called, `TestClass.mFooBar` and `fooPresenter.mFooBar` reference the same object(the mock object), but they are two distinct references to this object.

> Why does assertNull fail when it should have been set to null?

You are asserting the `Test.mFooBar`(belonging to the Test class) is null.  `Test.mFooBar` is created by in the test setup, but this variable is never set to null. On the other hand, the `fooPresenter.mFooBar` variable *is* explicitly set to null.  Again, while these variables point to the same object, the references themselves are not the same.

If you're looking to ensure that the `fooPresetner.mFooBar` is null, you could make it package-local or expose it with a property.  Doing this just for test purposes is generally frowned upon.

If you're looking to ensure that some action is performed on the `mFooBar` object in the constructor, you could write a test like the following:

```
public class TestClass {

    interface FooBar {
        void releaseSomething();
    }

    @Rule
    public MockitoRule r = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @Mock
    FooBar mFooBar;

    @Test
    public void testThatObjectsAreNullifiedInOnDestroy() {
        new FooPresenter(mFooBar).onDestroy();
        verify(mFooBar).releaseSomething();
    }

    class FooPresenter {
        private FooBar mFooBar;

        public FooPresenter(FooBar fooBar) {this.mFooBar = fooBar;}

        @Override
        void onDestroy() {
            mFooBar.releaseSomething();
            mFooBar = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Good Luck & Happy Testing!

Comment: This did answer my specific question. With this information, what I did for my case was to verifyNoMoreInterations on all of the mocked objects in my class after onDestroy is called; this was done because I agree that making coding changes such as this for test purposes is frowned upon. Thanks